# Limiting memory for varnish process

Tags: caching, limit, varnish

On Varnishv4.1 when i use ram as backend for Caching,when Reqests comes to it
after a while the amount of server's ram begans to full little by little and after it completely fills, the server crashes
and again it starts caching in the ram

I assign following variables in systemd service file for varnish.service
but still it does its Previous behavior and it crushs again:

```
LimitMEMLOCK=14336
MemoryLimit=13G
MemoryHigh=13G
MemoryMax=13G
```

How can i limit and specify the special amonut of memory that it cant exceed from that?

```
#Version used:
Varnishv4.1
#Operating System and version:
Ubuntu16.04
#Source of binary packages used (if any)
Installed from official ubuntu packages
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to limit both malloc and Transient.
I.e. as startup parameters `-s malloc,3GB s Transient,1GB`

In general the RAM allocated for Varnish should not exceed the 80% of total RAM avaiable on the system

Comment: How can i limit and specify the special amonut of memory that it cant exceed from that?

***This is important for me that when the amount of ram get fill, varnish start removing the old object from the end of ram and insert new object to ram and server doesn't crash.***

I should Sum this 2 factors and  resault is amount of memory that varnish will use?
malloc,3GB + Transient,1GB=4GB ram that varnish will use(Limitation for varnish ram proccess is 4G)
?
am i right?

Comment: I insert this line `-s malloc,3GB s Transient,1GB ` to my varnish config file but it shows an error : ` Error: Too many arguments (Transient,1G...)` or `this argument doesnt exist`. how can i specify the amount of Transient?

Comment: you forgot the "-" before the second s

Comment: I add "-" before s but this time it shows that this it shows this message and didnt start:
`Unknown storage method "Transient"`